# Load all fragments on ViewPager onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I lack some understanding of how to do this and most examples I've seen either don't seem to be applicable in my situation or absolutely confuse me.

**My Problem:**
I have 4 fragments, 2 for data submission, and 2 for data review and data calculations. The only way my code is able to pull from the last two fragments seems to be from the main `FragmentActivity`. The issue is that not all of my fragments are loaded when the Activity goes to through the onCreate method and when I try to declare an `onClickListener` I get a `NullPointerException` because that page hasn't been loaded yet.

Now I do have `setOffscreenPageLimit` set to 3 so that shouldn't be an issue at all, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the pages to load when the activity starts.

**Code:**

The line that causes the app force close is the declaration/execution of `btnEnterChemicals`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.swipe_chemicals);

    //declarations
    ...
    some declarations
    ...

    //Set up ViewPager and allow app to hold prior pages when off screen
    ChemicalsAdapter = new ResultsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ChemicalsPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.chemicals_pager);        
    ChemicalsPager.setAdapter(ChemicalsAdapter);
    ChemicalsPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    //When SwipeReviewResults is displayed, fill EditText's with data from other fragments
    ChemicalsPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            if (position == 2) {
                //Pull values from Chemicals 1
                ...
                some assignments
                ...

                //Pull values from Chemicals 2
                ...
                some assignments
                ...

                //Declare rvw text boxes for Meter Review 1
                ...
                some assignments
                ...

                //Declare rvw text boxes for Meter Review 2
                ...
                some assignments
                ...

                //If data isn't null, perform calculations on client entries
                if (data != null)
                {                       
                    //Do calculations before displaying values in review pages
                    ...
                    some calculations
                    ...


                    //Display results
                    ...
                    display results
                    ...
                }

                //Copy entered data to Chemicals Review 1
                ...
                display results
                ...

                //Copy entered data to Chemicals Review 2
                ...
                display results
                ...

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }
    });

    //Insert data into database
    class insertNew implements Runnable
    {
        ...
        data submission
        ...
    }

    //Declare and set OnClickListener for Entering Results
    final Button btnEnterChemicals = (Button) ChemicalsPager.findViewById(R.id.btnEnterChemicals);
    btnEnterChemicals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //set and encode url for data submission
            ...
            prepare data
            ...

            //Declare and start thread
            Thread thrInsertNew = new Thread(new insertNew(url));
            thrInsertNew.start();

        }
    });
```

Thank you for all of your help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your onClickListener be implemented on the onCreate method of the fragment that contains said Button?

In the examples I have seen so far, you create a Fragment (Java class and XML file) for each of the Tabs you want to implement and then you tell the PagerAdapter which one corresponds to which position.
As you said, the btnEnterChemicals Button does not exists until the page has loaded, so the correct way to add it's onCLickListener would be inside the corresponding fragment's onCreate method. I'm not sure if this addresses your question correctly. Please let me know.

PS: Try reading [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for help on how to communicate between Fragments and the activity that contains them.